# Issue with pagination using SQL Server and JQgrid,

Tags: sql, sql-server, coldfusion, jqgrid

I have the following code where from the query I'm trying to get the first 500 records and then next 500 and so on .

Here is my code, I'm stuck as to what and where I should make the change to make it work

```
<cffunction name="queryConvertForJQGRID" access="package" returntype="struct" output="no"> 
    <cfargument name="q" type="query" required="yes"> 
    <cfargument name="page" type="numeric" required="no" default="1"> 
    <cfargument name="rows" type="numeric" required="no" default="10"> 
    <cfset var result = structnew()> 
    <cfset var rowStruct = structnew()> 
    <cfset var col = ""> 
    <cfset result["page"] = arguments.page> 
    <cfset result["total"] = ceiling(arguments.q.recordcount/arguments.rows)> 
    <cfset result["records"] = arguments.q.recordcount> 
    <cfset result["rows"] = arraynew(1)> 
    <cfoutput query="arguments.q" startrow="#(arguments.page-1)*arguments.rows+1#" maxrows="#arguments.rows#"> 
      <cfset rowStruct = structnew()> 
      <cfset rowStruct['viewed'] = viewed>
      <cfset rowStruct['id'] = q['id'][currentrow]> 
      <cfset rowStruct['status'] = q['status'][currentrow]> 
      <cfset rowStruct['template'] = q['template'][currentrow]> 
      <cfset rowStruct['line'] = q['line'][currentrow]>
      <cfset rowStruct['error_message'] = q['error_message'][currentrow]>
      <cfset rowStruct['error_type'] = q['error_type'][currentrow]>
      <cfset rowStruct['datein'] = q['datein'][currentrow]> 
      <cfset arrayappend(result.rows, rowStruct)> 
    </cfoutput>
    <cfreturn result /> 
  </cffunction>

  <cffunction name="getgrouped" returntype="any" access="remote" output="false">
    <cfargument name="table" required="true" default="errors">
    <cfargument name="usedsn" default="" required="true">
    <cfargument name="callback" default="" required="false">
    <cfargument name="page" required="no" default="1">
    <cfargument name="rows" required="no" default="500">
    <cfargument name="sidx" required="no" default="">
    <cfargument name="sord" required="no" default="ASC">
    <cfargument name="acelem" required="no" type="any">
    <cfset var dsn = dsnSettings(arguments.usedsn)>
    <cfset var groupedget = "">
    <cfset var result = structnew()> 
    <cfset var rowStruct = structnew()> 
    <cfset var col = ""> 
    <cfset result["rows"] = arraynew(1)> 
    <cfquery name="groupedget" datasource="#dsn#">
        WITH List AS (
            SELECT row_number() over(ORDER BY mi.id) AS rowNum 
                , viewed
                , status
                , mi.errorid
                , FORMAT(datein, 'MMMM d, yyyy h:mm:ss tt PST', 'en-US') AS datein
                , mi.error_message
                , upper(mi.error_type) AS error_type
                , mi.line
                , mi.template
                , mi.id
            FROM #arguments.table# mi
        )
        , ListRecordCount AS (
            SELECT *
            FROM List , ( SELECT MAX(rowNum) AS recordCount FROM List ) recordCount
        )
        SELECT *
        FROM ListRecordCount
        WHERE rowNum BETWEEN #page# AND #rows#
    </cfquery>
    <cfset q = groupedget>
    <cfreturn queryConvertForJQGRID(q, arguments.page, arguments.rows)>
  </cffunction>
```

But it queries only 500 rows and that's it, no more pagination happening in the JQgrid.

Comment: Are you ALSO returning the total # of records available, along with the data? If not, that is why it doesn't paginate. It thinks there are ONLY 500 records total.

Comment: There are 2048 records and if i run the query in sql server, it gives a column named as: recordcount

http://prntscr.com/m0opde

Comment: Problem seems as to how i am using it, i am not sure what is going wrong

Comment: Side note, the query is very vulnerable to sql injection. Definitely fix that after you've resolved he pagination issue.

Comment: Not sure if this thread is up to date, but it does say that isn't the correct way to return the total number of rows https://stackoverflow.com/a/20984215/8895292  . For pagination, you typically run two queries: 1 - to get the total rows available and 2. Second to get the data to display.  Then pass both the total # rows AND the data back to the plugin.  See also the documentation here: http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:options

Comment: yeah, i had gone through that docs beforehand but after struggling for hours, i posted my frustration and i hope  other pair of eyes can see and can help me fix it

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't test it right now. Did you try what the thread above suggested? I.e. Add "total", etc... Pretty sure that is what you need AND the same JSON parameters are used in their server side PHP example Advanced > Search big sets http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html

Comment: I tried your solution, but i am confused at one section which is `WHERE rowNum BETWEEN #page# AND #rows#` and the cfoutput having maxrows attribute, what i am doing wrong there

Comment: Sorry, I missed that you are already passing "total" and "records" in your JSON. I think the problem is the *values* being passed.  The `total` (pages) and `records` should be the total *available* overall (not just what's in the current page of records) . So `records` should = 2048 and `total` (pages) should = 2048 / records per page.  So like I was saying, I think you need to run an additional query to get the total records available, ie `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM someTable ....`.

Comment: What version of SQL? And what version of CF? For pagination, most flavors of SQL can do a very good job of it themselves, which looks like this may essentially be doing, but I think jqGrid may only want one trip to the db and pass pagination to the client. I don't know that 2000 records is quite a "big data set". Also, `FROM #arguments.table#` can be _EXTREMELY_ dangerous. Make sure you sanitize that input very thoroughly, especially in a `remote` access function. And unless all of the tables you're accessing have all of those requested columns, there's not really a need for a dynamic `FROM`.

Comment: Correction: No, your query is only paginating your CTE, so it's probably hitting a full record set for every page of data, and then whittling it down to just your window of data. And then recreating a struct of nested data to send back to jqGrid. All of the data you need should already be available in your original query, so you may just need to massage it to get it into the format jqGrid wants. How are you calling the `getGrouped` function? Can you provide some example data?

Comment: @Shawn - It's not that it is a "Big data set", just that the example confirms what parameters are needed to paginate ;-) Anyway, I may have read it wrong, but ... ignoring the sql injection issues for a moment (i.e. table name AND rownum), seemed like the code IS paginating correctly i.e. within the SQL. The only thing it seemed to be doing wrong is using the *current page* query to calculate total pages/records available. Obviously, `arguments.q.recordcount` will only return 500 instead of 2048.  (cont'd)

Comment: Granted, they could use the existing `ListRecordCount` column in the current page query too. However, personally I think a separate query is cleaner than duplicating the total count with *every* record (or even using a stored proc) but either would work. It's just a matter of whether you prefer duplicating data to save a db call or not..

Comment: @Ageax I think I was thinking out loud. Been a while since I've used jqGrid, but I _think_ it needs the entire dataset to do things like sorting and searching. JS should be able to chew over 2K records pretty easily in most modern clients, but 10K+ might be a beast. Regardless, I reformatted the query and realized it's actually 2 CTEs that are pulling the entire dataset and then filtering to paginate, so it will likely hit the db multiple times. There's also a comma-syntax join in the 2nd CTE for the recordcount (that's not really needed) that should be corrected. ... 1/2

Comment: 2/2 ... And we all know that comma-syntax JOINs make my eye twitch. :-) It's essentially a cartesian join (table A rows X table B rows), but since there's only one row for the count, it doesn't really make a difference. It just could be optimized. I think the first thing that needs to happen is the query needs to be fixed. But I'm kinda getting off into the weeds here. I'll take a look at it, but without some example data or how this is being called, I'm afraid my answer my be limited in usefulness.

Comment: Guys, using this in the query at the end: `#((arguments.page - 1) * rows) + 1# AND #((arguments.page * rows) -1)#` fxed the issue, but i am ok if i get better sql for handling paging

Comment: Are you doing any of the sorting or searching on your results, or are you just using jqGrid to display paged versions of your results? If you have 2048 records in this result set, you'll be making 5 calls to your database to get these results (500&500&500&500&48). But the query has no ordering, so you could _theoretically_ be calling back 5 sets of 500 random rows from your database. Plus if someone adds or deletes rows, your returns could be skewed. You aren't necessarily retrieving all rows or only retrieving each row once. I would definitely look at refactoring the query.

Comment: *using this in the query at the end: ...fxed the issue* That's not using the ACTUAL row count in the table, so it may be wrong in some scenarios.